# intel MKL: what function used in MKL lib (only for C program) for solving Ax=lambda*Bx (eigen value)

Tags: eigenvector, eigen, intel-mkl

```
Ax=lambda*Bx
```

how to find the value of lambda using MKL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best function to call depends on the structure and data types of your matrices.  Intel provides [this guide on function selection for various eigen value solutions](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/win/mkl/refman/lse/lse_intro.html) .

To set up your inputs, consult the 
[MKL Notes on calling from c](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-blas-cblas-and-lapack-compilinglinking-functions-fortran-and-cc-calls/#1)

Here's a snippet:

> When calling LAPACK routines from C-language programs, make sure that you follow Fortran rules: Pass variables by 'address' as opposed to pass by 'value'. Be sure to store your data Fortran-style, i.e. data stored column-major rather than row-major order.